# Google Chrome is crashing everytime I try to uninstall a Chrome app (not an extension)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, uninstallation

I couldn't find the same problem anywhere. I'm trying to uninstall some Chrome apps (for instance, Helium), that appear below the extensions page. Everytime I click to uninstall any of them, Google pauses for 1-2sec and then crashes. After opening it again, they appear again. It's really annoying, because Chrome is crashing from time to time and I presume it's because some app incompatibility (I uninstalled most extensions already).

Any other way to uninstall a Chrome app? I tried to delete the folder in C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Web Applications but it still appears.

Still no success... Anyone?

Comment: Off the top of my mind, have you tried uninstalling Chrome, deleting all Chrome files, and then reinstall again? It does sound like you have encountered a specific corner case. Maybe big hammer will be your solution.

Comment: Yes I did!
This happens after I sync chrome with my account: then all the apps appear again and I can't uninstall.

Is there any way to just "remove" all the apps and extensions from my account, for instance, so I can sync it again without adding them?

Comment: You'll probably get better support if you contact Chrome support team directly. This is, as far as I can see, not a widely occurring problem. You can link to this question on stackoverflow.com for reference

Comment: I experience the same issue consistently across multiple platforms. The PWA implementation in Chrome, ChromeOS and Andriod is horribly buggy in lots of ways.